# Problematic Property Setting

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, runtime, startup

I am building a project with the WindowsFormsApplication libraries and everything was going well until I noticed that the class properties are not being set at runtime anymore. The first instance occurred when I set menustrip hotkeys: the set in the designer, the code for it is there, I made sure nothing else would be sneakily altering the value(s) at runtime by using methods instead of the 'property' format. Then, somehow I managed to fix this by calling a method created specifically for setting menustrip hotkeys right after the initialization method.

NOW, the docking properties will not set or, in other words: I set a control's dock style to dockstyle.fill and when I maximize the window, it's as if the dock style was never set, but the code that says-so, is still there! the dock-fill property was working successfully only a moment ago...

I've searched for problems similar to mine for a good day and only found [one result](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/878558-datagridview-properties-not-being-set-when-called-form-load), but the questioner wasn't provided good answers ~in my opinion. I don't have much time so any help would be much appreciated!

In the mean time, I'll port all the controls over to a new form. That seemed to do the trick for two other occurrences with past projects...

Comment: Please provide some snips of the code, including where it is being called from.  Hard to provide answers without seeing it.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't know what to post really... because I don't even know what's going on. I've stripped generated code to mar basics where guaranteed results would fly. If I was to post all the code, well, that's a lot (literally).
I seemed to have found this problem is occurring mostly within menustrip items; I rebuilt one of the contextmenustrips from scratch again and that so happened to fix my docking problem... JUST a head-ache!

Answer (score 0):

I have had bizarre results with Visual Studio sometimes losing it's mind.  Exiting and restarting seems to fix it.  What version are you using?

Comment: VCS2010 ~ I didn't spend the time to see exactly what the code was that was causing the issue, but I rewrote the toolstripitem lists (at least for the context menu), and things started working again... though I can't say if hot-keys are still being avoided(haven't checked)